# Add-AzureADServicePrincipalOwner problems

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to add ServicePrincipal owner using PowerShell.
I run `Add-AzureADServicePrincipalOwner` and it returned success. I verify above with `Get-AzureADServicePrincipalOwner`, but in the portal, I cannot see the newly added user. Moreover, the newly added user has error when running for example:

```
New-AzureRmADAppCredential -ApplicationId $azureRmADServicePrincipal.ApplicationId -Password $SecureStringPassword
New-AzureRmADAppCredential : Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
At line:1 char:1
```

```

What I did wrong? Or what am I miss to run it properly

Comment: Are you the administrator of that active directory?

Comment: I became Global Administrator using Azure Ad privileges, so I'm not permanent, but in the moment of invocation I am